# Karate - java 11 - Issues

Tags: karate

I am currently using Karate Apache 0.9.6.  I was advised my servers are being moved to Java 11.  I was advised to move towards Java 11, as well.  I updated my Karate Apache to use the Karate-Core 1.0.1 in my Maven POM.  I am still seeing that my karate-config.js is not being read at all.  I am getting Polyglot Exception: > js failed: 01.  I am also having issues with generating the cucumber reports.  Is there an help with migrating from Apache 0.9.6 to Karate-Core 1.01. with Java 11?

I also see some others posting on the same issue but upgrading from a different version.  [Getting `org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError:` - after upgrading to karate 1.1.0.RC3 from karate 0.9.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68189314/getting-org-graalvm-polyglot-polyglotexception-referenceerror-after-upgrad)

Comment: there is absolutely no way to help you unless you follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - and please use 1.1.0.RC4

Comment: and it sounds like you haven't read the upgrade guide: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

Comment: Thank you so much Peter. for the quick response.  I was looking at the wrong link for sure.